# Command through Serial monitor does not properly work in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, string, serial-data

I am executing a function in Arduino by giving String input to the serial monitor.

The issue here is when I enter `SHOW$`, the function `showData()` works but when I enter the same `SHOW$`, it doesn't gets called.
I want to call the function `showData()` every time i enter the `SHOW$` text into the serial console.

My question here is to what mistake I am doing here, and what is the solution for this.

```
String strReq = "";
char inChar = 0;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

  while (Serial.available())
  {
    inChar = Serial.read();

    if (inChar == '$') {

     Serial.println(" Received String :");
     Serial.print(strReq);
  
     if (strReq.equalsIgnoreCase("SHOW"))
       showData();

     Serial.flush();
     strReq = "";

    } else {

      strReq = strReq + inChar;
    }
  }
}

void showData() {
  Serial.print("Showing Information");
}
```

Comment: how is line ending set in Serial Monitor? it is possible that the second time you add line end characters from previous input to strReq

Comment: both NL & CR is set

Comment: then the second input is "\r\nSHOW" and this is not equal to SHOW

Comment: right because next time it is printing with new line.. how to solve this.?

Comment: one option is to ignore control caracters when reading. `else if (inChar >= 32) {`

Comment: what other option is there. because there are too many strings i am comparing in original code.

actually serial data output doesn't matter to me. I am turning LED on and off on this command , it is not executing in the second time as explained in the question.

Comment: Do you know what `Serial.flush()` does?

Comment: @Majenko, flush waits until tx buffer is empty

Comment: @Juraj I'm not asking you. I know you know. Looking at the code I am thinking the java bee thinks it works how it did in pre-Arduino 1.0.0.

Comment: you could turn off the line ends in Serial Monitor

Comment: You could also use a *real* terminal emulator instead of the POS Serial "monitor".

Comment: @Majenko, sorry. I overlooked the flush() in OP's code

Comment: @Juraj If the OP assumed it worked how it used to (clears the RX buffer contents) then the code would work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use String.trim() function. 
Thanks guys for giving a quick reply on the question.

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem seems to be not knowing what `Serial.flush()` does.

It pre-Arduino 1.0.0 times `Serial.flush()` used to clear any data in the serial's RX buffer. It would throw it away.  In your code that would throw away the line ending `\r\n` that is sent along with the command.

However in Arduino 1.0.0 it was changed to instead block execution until all bytes had been sent out of the Serial TX buffer.  This was deemed more useful, and a replacement to the original functionality is very easy to implement if needed.

This change was not widely documented, but it is mentioned in the manual:

> Waits for the transmission of outgoing serial data to complete. (Prior to Arduino 1.0, this instead removed any buffered incoming serial data.)

So with `Serial.flush()` acting like it does in current versions, you would get a different string the second time around.  You would see:

```
SHOW$
\r\nSHOW$
\r\nSHOW$
```

and so on.

You have come up with a "fix", which uses `String::trim()` to discard any leading and trailing non-printable characters, which removes the line-endings from your subsequent strings.  However it would be far better to ignore them in the first place and not need to do the trimming.

The simplest way would be to only add characters to your string if they are printable:

```
if (inChar == '$') {
 Serial.println(" Received String :");
 Serial.print(strReq);
 if (strReq.equalsIgnoreCase("SHOW"))
   showData();
 Serial.flush();
 strReq = "";
} else if (inChar >= ' ') { // << Only add if a space or above
  strReq = strReq + inChar;
}
```

A simple change, but one which then means you're not having to add the extra processing of trimming unwanted characters from the string.